Contradicting Results from Exact Diagonalization of Many-Body Hamiltonian
I am a little confused regarding a calculation I did, and I seem to be running into some sort of contradiction.
I was numerically solving a 1D interacting tight binding chain with N sites. To benchmark my numerical results, I exactly diagonalized the system for N = 3 and compared the results with my code. For N = 3, I considered the following Hamiltonian of spinless fermions with nearest neighbor interactions:
$$H = -t\sum_{i = 1}^{3} (c_{i}^{\dagger}c_{i+1} + H.c) + V\sum_{i=1}^{3}n_{i}n_{i+1}$$
where we have periodic boundary conditions (i.e. $n_{3+1}=n_{1}$).
Suppose we add two electrons to this system. I will denote the two electron basis states as $|12\rangle,|23\rangle, |31\rangle$, where $|12\rangle$ = $c_{1}^{\dagger}c_{2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle$ and so forth. In the two particle sector, the interaction part of $H$ acts trivially and simply shifts the energies of all two particle states  by $V$. Therefore, the problem is effectively non-interacting, and the ground state energy is simply the sum of the two lowest single particle energies ($-2t$ and $t$), plus the constant offset from the interaction, thus giving us $E_{0} = V-t$.
This all seems fine and dandy, and my numerics confirmed this result, however, for some reason I ran into a contradiction when explicitly diagonalizing this system by hand. Let us construct the Hamiltonian of this sector using the basis states I listed before. Doing so yields the following two-particle Hamiltonian:
$$\begin{pmatrix} V & -t & -t \\ -t & V & -t \\-t & -t & V\end{pmatrix}$$
This Hamiltonian has a ground state energy $V-2t$, which is different from the above result. Clearly, the $V-t$ result is correct, but why am I obtaining a different energy from the explicit diagonalization? Where did I go wrong in the construction of the above matrix?

Were you careful about the negative signs when anti-commuting the operators when computing the matrix elements of the Hamiltonian in the two-particle sector? To me, this is likely where the inconsistency is.  I suspect that one or two sets of the off-diagonals should be just $t$ rather than $-t$. I'm trying to work it out by hand right now to see if that's correct, but you should check!

I think you  have a typo. The $V\sum n_in_{i+1}$ terms are off-diagonal.

When I compute the matrix of the Hamiltonian in the two-particle sector for fermions, I get positive signs for the $t$'s rather than negative signs, and this leads to energies $V-t$ (with multiplicity 2) and $V+2t$. When I do it for bosons, I get the matrix in the OP, leading to energies $V-2t$ and $V+t$ (multiplicity 2). (@naturallyInconsistent: The $V$-term is diagonal in the basis specified in the OP, because the number operators $n_i$ are diagonal in this basis.)

@march Thank you for pointing out the anti-commutativity. I was sloppy with computing the matrix elements and I didn't realize that the fermion exchange affects the hopping. Thanks for correcting me.

Therefore, the problem is effectively non-interacting, and the ground state energy is simply the sum of the two lowest single particle energies - this is incorrect, because the interaction Hamiltonian does not commute with the single-particle part, in other words - it is not simple energy shift in the eigenbasis of the single-particle Hamiltonian.

@RogerV. No--what I said is not incorrect. The ground state energy for the two-particle sector of any system size is indeed given by the sum of the lowest single-particle energies plus a constant, $V(N-2)$. The fact that the interaction part of H doesn't commute with the kinetic part has nothing to do with my argument; for any system size N,  the interaction Hamiltonian acts trivially on the N-1 particle states, thus the problem is non-interacting within this sector.

What is single-particle energies for you? Zeros, or the results of diagonalizing Hamiltonian for $V=0$? You do not seem to differentiate between different single-particle bases.

@RogerV. The single particle energies are just the eigenvalues of $H_{0}$ (i.e. set V = 0 and fill up the energies of the non-interacting system). What other single-particle bases are you referring to? Also, I made a typo in the previous comment: in the second sentence, I meant to say “The ground state energy for the N-1 particle sector…”

The single-particle eigenstates are plane waves (with $N=3$), i.e., superpositions of the basis states used to write the Hamiltonian ($|1\rangle, |2\rangle$, etc.) your first calculation clearly uses the latter basis, not the eigenbasis.

@RogerV. I'm not really sure what your point is. The energies are independent of basis... it doesn't matter if you write the Hamiltonian in real or $k$-space.

Yes, but the single-particle part of the Hamiltonian is diagonal in momentum representation, not in the position representation, in which your initial argument is made. So I suggest calculating the eigenfunctions of the single-particle Hamiltonian, and expressing the coulomb interaction in their terms, and adding this to the Q... or perhaps even as an answer (which it might turn out to be.)

My guess is that the OP missed some negative signs when computing the matrix of the Hamiltonian in the two-particle sector that appear when anti-commuting the operators past each other.  Here is an example.  Consider the two-particle states
$$
\lvert 12\rangle =\hat{a}_1^{\dagger}\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\lvert 0\rangle
~~\mbox{ and }~~
\lvert 23\rangle =\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\lvert 0\rangle
\,.
$$
We will compute the expectation value of the operator
$$
\hat{H}_t = -t\sum_{j=1}^3\hat{a}_j^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j+1} + \mbox{H.c.}
$$
(where $3+1 = 4$ is the same as $1$) in this state, i.e., we'll compute
\begin{align}
\langle 12 \lvert \hat{H}_t \rvert 23 \rangle
&=
\langle 0 \lvert
\hat{a}_2\hat{a}_1
\left(-t\sum_{j=1}^3\hat{a}_j^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j+1}\right)
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\rvert 0 \rangle
+
\langle 0 \lvert
\hat{a}_2\hat{a}_1
\left(-t\sum_{j=1}^3\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j}\right)
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\rvert 0 \rangle
\\&=
-t 
\sum_{j=1}^3\langle 0 \lvert\hat{a}_2\hat{a}_1\hat{a}_j^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j+1}\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\rvert 0 \rangle
+
\sum_{j=1}^3\langle 0 \lvert\hat{a}_2\hat{a}_1\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j}\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\rvert 0 \rangle
\end{align}
We can reason out that only one of these six terms can be non-zero in the following way.
In the first sum, the operator $\hat{a}_j^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{j+1}$ will yield zero unless there is already a particle on site $j+1$, and so $j+1 = 2$ or $j+1=3$ in order that the matrix element be non-zero. If $j+1=3$, then $j=2$, and so the factor $\hat{a}_j^{\dagger} = \hat{a}_2^{\dagger}$ will put a particle on site 2; however, there's already a particle on site 2, and so this will yield zero. Thus, $j+1=2$ and $j=1$, which is to say that we'll then add one particle to site 1.  however, we'll also \emph{remove} a particle from site 2 (by acting with the $\hat{a}_2$ on the far left), but there is then no particle on site 2, and so we get 0.
In the second sum, we can similarly see that $j=2$ or $j=3$.  If $j=2$, then $j+1=3$, which means we remove the particle from site 2 and add it to site 3, but then there is no particle on site 2, and so the $\hat{a}_2$ on the left will try to remove a particle that's not there, and we get zero. f $j=3$, then $j+1=4 \to 1$, and so we remove a particle on site 3 (good: there's one there), and we add one to site 1. This works because we will then remove particles on site 1 and 2.
We'll compute this matrix element using the anti-commutation rule, given by
$$
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_j\hat{a}_{k}=\delta_{jk} - \hat{a}_{k}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_j\,,
$$
to put each term in normal order so that we can evaluate the expectation values easily. To do this, we focus on the operators and put the expression in normal order as
\begin{align}
\hat{a}_2\hat{a}_1\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_{3}
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
&=
\hat{a}_2
\left(1-\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1\right)
\left(- \hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}\right)
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\\&=
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
-
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}
\\&=
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\left(1- \hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}\right)
-
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\left(1- \hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}\right)
\\&=
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
-\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
-
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
+
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
\\&=
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1
\left(-\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_1\right)
-\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_1\hat{a}_1
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
-
\left(1-
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}\hat{a}_2\right)
+
\hat{a}_2
\hat{a}_2^{\dagger}
\hat{a}_3^{\dagger}\hat{a}_{3}
\,.
\end{align}
All but one term ends up with an annihilation operator on the right, and so each of these terms evaluates to zero when we put back the vacuum expectation value. The remaining term is just $-1$.  Combined with the $-t$ from the Hamiltonian, we get a matrix element equal to just $t$ (rather than $-t$). If we choose the third state to be $\lvert 31 \rangle = \hat{a}^{dagger}_3\hat{a}_1\lvert 0 \rangle$, then in fact all of these matrix elements will be equal to $t$. However, if we switch around the operators, i.e., define $\lvert 31 \rangle = \hat{a}_1\hat{a}^{dagger}_3\lvert 0 \rangle$, then this is the negative of the original state we chose, and so we'll get some $-t$'s in places instead. The result will always give the same eigenvalues though.
Thus, we can see that the anti-commutativity of the operators can change the values of the matrix elements. Given the choice of basis I've made, I get the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
V & t & t \\
t & V & t\\
t & t& V
\end{bmatrix}\,,
$$
whose eigenvalues are $V-t$ (with degeneracy 2) and $V+2t$.

An elegant way of solving this problem is by using hole transformation:
$$
h_i=c_i^\dagger,\\ h_i^\dagger=c_i,
$$
where the whole creation operators act on a state filled with electrons:
$$
|full\rangle=c_1^\dagger c_2^\dagger c_3^\dagger |0\rangle.
$$
The Hamiltonian then takes form (after normal reodering):
$$
H=t\sum_i \left( h_i^\dagger h_{i+1}+ h.c.\right)+
3V + 2V\sum_i h_i^\dagger h_i + V\sum_i h_i^\dagger h_i h_{i+1}^\dagger h_{i+1}
$$
We are interested in solutions with a single hole ($N-2=1$), which are superpositions of single-hole states $h_i^\dagger |full\rangle$, while the matrix elements if the last term in the Hamiltonian between these states are zero. Thus, we solve a single-particle tight-binding problem in terms of plane waves, with the energies:
$$
E(k) = 2t\cos(k) + V, k=0, \pm \frac{2\pi}{3}
$$
That is we have eigenvalues $V+2t$ and $V-t$.
